# Apache FOP 2.1 basic-link

Tags: java, apache, xslt, apache-fop

I am building some reports using Apache FOP 2.1 using Java 1.6.0_45 (due to constraints of the deployment environment).  I have also tried using Java 1.8.0_45 to no avail.  I am attempting to embed a pair of links into the document, one to an external help portal and the second a mailto to a contact email address.  Both links are being built with what appears to be binary gibberish values for the URL.  They don't equate to anything useful when inspected in a hex editor.  I have simplified my test to link to google.com and still received similar output.  Here are some examples:

**XSL:FO output:**
`<fo:basic-link external-destination="url('http://www.google.com')" color="blue" text-decoration="underline">TEST</fo:basic-link>`

**Copy Link Location in Acrobat:**
`file:///C|/dev/projects/customer/project/reporting/˜áþ€-¶
¶@ŒœØ÷“)í6`

**URL Opened in Chrome:**
`file:///C:/dev/projects/customer/project/reporting/%98%0B%17%E1%FE%80-%B6%0A%B6@%8C%9C%7F%D8%F7%93%0B)%ED6`

**XSL:FO Output**
`<fo:basic-link external-destination="http://www.google.com" color="blue" text-decoration="underline">TEST</fo:basic-link>`

**Copy Link Location in Acrobat:**
`file:///C|/dev/projects/customer/project/reporting/Kþ#`ÈD Û;!a×•A‚×„âs`

**URL Opened in Chrome:**
`file:///C:/dev/projects/customer/project/reporting/K%FE#`ÈD Û;!a×%05•A‚×„â%13s`

The fo:block element is a child of an fo:block element which is, in turn, a child of an fo:table-cell element.  Does it appear that I am doing anything incorrectly?  I've searched for this issue as well as known issues with FOP 2.1 but found nothing similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case the behaviour was different in the sense of "more okay" in earlier fop versions, I'd suggest to file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

With a little more digging, I found that the issue with links is only when encryption is enabled (which, of course, I am doing).  With that bit of information, I was able to find that this has been a known issue since 2004.  You can find the Jira ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-916.  There is a work around listed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2279 that I can confirm works.